# The area of a thin slice of a sphere

Tags: geometry, calculus

In derivation of the shell theorem it is claimed that the area of the this slice as drawn here

[image]

equals $A = 2\pi R \sin \theta \cdot R d\theta$. But why? If were a cylinder 
of height $Rd\theta$, then I'd agree, but it isn't a cylinder.

Comment: You can think of that area as lying in between two cylinders. The difference between the radii of said cylinders is something of the form $R\cos\theta\text d\theta$, so that the difference of area between them is of order $\text d\theta^2$.

Comment: the area is the same as that of a circular cylinder having the same height tangent to the sphere (circumscribed cylinder)

Comment: I asked the same question and got a good answer. Go to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708115/the-area-of-thin-ring-of-shell-of-a-sphere)

Answer (score 4):

Because $d\theta$ is infinitesimally small the edge of the colored section can be approximated by a straight line. Exactly like a curve can be approximated by it's tangent in every point.  So the total section can be seen as a cylinder which justifies the use of the formula for the surface of a cylinder.

The next example will perhaps make it easier to visualize. As seen from space the earth is a sphere (globally, over large distances), however when you look outside the window you see a flat surface (locally, over small distances).

Comment: Yes, but we could approximate it with a truncated cone (either inscribed or circumscribed), or even a truncated n-hedron. And these approximations don't have to give us the same resut.

Comment: That's not necessary! The method used in your question isn't an approximation (like a tangent line isn't an approximation in that one point!). You are actually almost working with 2D objects (slice the sphere in circles) of which you calculate the perimeter and than you integrate over all the perimeters of all the 2D objects. However because you would end up with a length instead of a surface you need to give the 2D objects a thickness that is so small that your calculations are still exact, but not zero because you want to end up with a surface!

Comment: Ok, but why exactly $R d\theta$? How do we know that by setting the height to $R d\theta$ we will get the exact result?

Comment: You can see this directly from the figure in your question. The length of the arc of the colored section is exactly equal to $Rd\theta$. If you didn't know this already you can easily understand this in the following way: The perimeter of a circle is $2\pi R$ and there are exactlye $2\pi$ radiants in 360°. So if you want to know the lenght of an arc that corresponds to an angle $d\theta$ you get: $2\pi R / 2\pi * d\theta$. And ofcourse you want the infenitessimal surfaces to be expressed in quantities related to the sphere.

Comment: Yes, I know that the arc length *is* $Rd\theta$. Still, why is the approximation with $Rd\theta$ exact. Using a truncated cone would seem a better approximation. (although more clumsy) I know it's similar, but I'm not convinced it's exact (purely mathematically)

Comment: Lets try this another way. Imagine we start from the truncated cone like you say. Imagine the cone has a finite height. We can think of the cone as two circles with different radii connected by a third surface. Obviously the height of your cone would still have to be $Rd\theta$! Because $d\theta$ is a differential, the height infenitessimally small (this means you take the limit of $d\theta \rightarrow 0$). Now imagine what happens to the two circles of your cone as the height goes to 0: they coincide and have the same radii. We thus have a cilinder!

Comment: @marmistrz it seems to me as you need a [refresh on the subject of Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral).