# The area of thin ring of shell of a sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry

In a proof of the [Shell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem), it is stated that the area of a thin ring of shell of a sphere is $2\pi R^2 \sin(\theta) d\theta$.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep6lo.png)

**With shallow search, I could not find any proof of this. I should mention that this question was already asked in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602840/the-area-of-a-thin-slice-of-a-sphere#) but no good answer was given and furthermore, I have a follow-up question as well.

Therefore, the question is as follows:

Is this just an approximation?
If so, if we use another approximation, would we get the same result (I don't think so)?
If not, why am I getting a different result:

*method 1:* Using spherical cap area. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) - no further explanation.

*method 2:*

area$ \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2\pi r_i^* \Delta x \rightarrow \text{area}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2\pi r_i^* \Delta x$

The limit exists, therefore:

area= $\displaystyle \int_{R\cos(\theta+d\theta)}^{R\cos(\theta)} 2\pi \sqrt{R^2 - x^2} \ dx$

For simplification, let $0 \le x \le R$ (instead of $-R \le x \le R$.) Now substitude $x$ with $R\sin(\psi)$ where $0 \le \psi \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ holds. Then

area= $\displaystyle \int_{\pi/2-(\theta+d\theta)}^{\pi/2-\theta} 2\pi R^2 \cos^2(\psi)\ d\psi =\ \left. 2\pi R^2 (\frac{\psi}{2} + \frac{\sin(2\psi)}{4}) \right ]_{\pi/2-(\theta+d\theta)}^{\pi/2-\theta} \neq 2\pi R^2 \sin(\theta) d\theta$

Am I wrong?

Thank you very much for reading this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1 is consistent with approximating the area of a thin ring $2πR^2sin(θ)dθ$, which you can check by integration. But I think the formula for spherical cap area is usually obtained by integration, so this is some sort of circular reasoning.

Method 2 is incorrect. You are missing an infinitesimal length when you substitute $dx$ for $ds = \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$, but after integration the difference will be finite. The correct way to do it is to use $ds$ in your formula.

More generally and rigorously we define the area of some surface by double integration in Cartesian coordinate system, and use a Jacobian to convert an infinitesimal area expressed in $dx,dy$ to $dr,d\theta$.

If we assume $x=rsin(\theta)cos(\phi), y =rsin(\theta)sin(\phi)$ then $J = r^2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$. So to integrate on a sphere, we write
$$I = \int_{-R}^{R}dx\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}dy f(x,y)\frac{1}{cos(\theta)}=\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi f(\theta, \phi) r^2sin(\theta)$$
In shell theorem, $f$ is independent of $\phi$, so we can do the integral for $\phi$ and get our partial result
$$I =\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta f(\theta) 2\pi r^2 sin(\theta)$$

Comment: Hi,
First of all, thank you for the response. But I'm still a bit confused.

1. The Cap Area method:
According to Wikipedia, the area of (specified) cap= $2\pi R h$ which gives the desired area as $2\pi R ( (R-R\cos(\theta + d\theta)) - (R-R\cos(\theta)) )= 2\pi R^2 (\cos(\theta) - \cos(\theta + d\theta)) \neq 2\pi R^2 \sin(\theta) d\theta$.
So what am I doing wrong?

2. About the method 2:
Could you elaborate more? On why my method is wrong and on why replacing with ds works? what is my elementary object that by limiting defines my area?

(out of characters :) - to be continued :D )

Comment: 3. About the Jacobian method:
Let's define area as you suggested. The formula that I'm familiar with is
$\iint_D \sqrt{ f_x(x, y)^2 + f_y(x, y)^2 + 1 ) } \ dA$.
Accordingly, by considering the hemisphere $z= \sqrt{R^2 - x^2 -y^2}$ we deduce that the desired integral is $\iint_D \frac{R^2}{R^2-x^2-y^2} \ dA$. by converting to polar coordinate it gives 
$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{R\sin(\theta)}^{R\sin(\theta+d\theta)} \frac{R^2r}{R^2-r^2} \ dr \ d\theta$, which honestly I was unable to integrate completely.
This does not conform to what you are saying, So could you elaborate more?
Thanks again

Comment: @Aria Replacing $dx$ with $ds$ has clear geometric implication, if you imagine you are measuring the area of some cloth lying on a curved surface. The area of a thin ring is not the actual area of a thin ring, since $d\theta$ does not make sense unless in an integral to be integrated, so you can understand it as a partial result of the surface integral. I think putting sin(\theta+d\theta) in the integral upper limit does not make sense. If you are doing a surface integral, $d\theta$ should be in the integrand, because it is the basic fabric of our integration. For the Jacobian, I edited answer

Comment: Sorry I gave an incorrect Jacobian. Now I give the exact calculation, is it clear now? Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. :) Now I completely understand why I was wrong. But could you please explaine $f(x,y) 1/\cos(\theta)$ a bit more? How shell’s theorem gives this? (What is f exactly? The resulting vector of gravitational rule?) thanks again.

Comment: $1/cos(/theta)$ is just a projection factor. Roughly we have $dScos(\theta)=dxdy$. $f$ can be thought of as density, something you want to integrate on a surface.